# Guassian Process Regression - feature selection

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, feature-selection, gaussian-process

I'm using guassian process regression to do some modeling. One issue I'm encountering is feature selection for some of my models, which often have many relevant features. I'm not sure what the best way to reduce the # of features is. I understand that some covariance functions in GPR use automatic relevance detection, but I believe there are some assumptions on the features that these methods require (I think independence between features for ARD). Anyone dealt with these issues before? Any suggestions on the best approach to reduce features or create independent features from existing ones? Is there a preprocessing method that might help? I've looked at PCA but features are only guaranteed independence if joint normally distributed, which I'm not sure my features are.

I find GPR to be more accurate when there are fewer features, and I have hundreds of potential features that I could use.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Gaussian process regression you are assuming the Xts are jointly normal.  I don't know what you mean by more accurate.  With hundreds of possible features to choose from and no idea about how to reduce it down you will have difficulty no matter what method you use for feature selection. PCA has an interpretation regardless of any normality assumption.  The first principal component is a linear combination of the features that explain the largest amount of variation in your dependent variable.

Comment: The second is the one orthogonal to the first that expains the largest percentage of the remaining variation and so on. But the principla components are linear combinations of all your features.  if you use prinicpal components you can reduce the number of variables only in the sense that the number of principal components describing the dependent variable can be a lot smaller than the number of original features.  But they don't reduce the number of features used.